# How can I reach this solution, update & delete inside rails loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm newbie on `ruby on rails` I have a list like:

[Item List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkWrQ.png)

Controller code:

```
def postList
   @post_list = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 4).order('post_id DESC')
end
```

view:

```
<% @post_list.each do |post| %>
 <%= post.post_title %>

 <div class="btn btn-success"> Add </div>
 <div class="btn btn-danger"> Delete </div>
<% end %>
```

I need if I click `Add` then update 1 into the database which is column_name `add` & click `Delete` then delete this raw from `DB`.

How can I use form inside this loop?

How can I reach this solution?

It would be great if any one help.

Comment: When the `add` button is clicked what should happen?

Comment: When click `Add` then update `1` then all post will publish which is `add == 1` that's it

Answer (score 0):

#### The view

```
<% @post_list.each do |post| %>
 <%= post.post_title %>

 #This will post to the update action.
 <%= form_for post do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :add, value: 1 %>
   <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-success"  %>
 <% end %>
 
 #This will post to the destroy action
 <%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(post), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

#### PostsController

```
def update
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.update(params.require(:post).permit(:add))
end

def destroy
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.destroy
end
```

You can enhance a bit more using AJAX so you will add `remote: true` to the link and form and respond to AJAX calls from your controller

Comment: Showing error `undefined method each for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Make sure the `@post_list` is assigned in your controller action